# Eclipse Oxygen does not seem to have an option to configure external folder for plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

The Eclipse wiki gives the solution but cannot find this option help/software updates/manage configurations in Eclipse Oxygen:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_I_install_plug-ins_outside_the_main_install_directory%3F

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-externalize-my-eclipse-plugins.html?page=2

Comment: It is not 100 % clear what you are asking about to me. It think you are asking about the dropins folder. It works the same way in Oxygen as in previous releases. See the [documentation about the dropins folder](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html&resultof=%22%64%72%6f%70%69%6e%73%22%20%22%64%72%6f%70%69%6e%22%20).

Comment: That second link is very old and refers to the original Eclipse update system which was replaced by the 'p2' system years ago.

Comment: I want to install all my plugins in an external folder so that i do not have to reinstall plugins should i decide to do a clean install of another eclipse instance. To do that , the links tell that we need to configure in eclipse the folder location and create a directory structure similar to plugins folder of eclipse. I can create the directory structure (preferably in our workspace) but cannot find the option help/software updates/manage configurations in Eclipse Oxygen. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: You can do that by downloading all of your plugins and putting them in a folder called `dropins` in the Eclipse installation folder. I don't think that will be convenient, though. I think its doable using the Eclipse Installer, but I haven't figured out how. I'd also like to know... Perhaps the info is in [this tutorial](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/).